# Zabbix adding Windows 10 client

Tags: zabbix-agent

I am trying to add a Windows 10 host after installing the Zabbix 6.4.2 server.

My setup is the server runs on a VMWare VM on my home lab and I can login OK.

I then tried to add a Windows 10 client by installing Zabbix Agent 2 and entering the LAN IP of my Zabbix server.

I know they can see each other because they can both ping each other but there is not data being reported from the agent.

I also tried to add the client as a host in the server in case setup is required both ends, but still no data reported.

The log file hints at a error but do not know what.

```
2023/09/18 14:59:55.933949 [101] active check configuration update from host [GHWS06] started to fail
2023/09/18 15:00:07.938077 [101] cannot connect to [192.168.110.104:10051]: dial tcp :0->192.168.110.104:10051: i/o timeout
2023/09/18 15:00:07.938077 [101] sending of heartbeat message for [GHWS06] started to fail
2023/09/18 15:00:09.952721 [101] active check configuration update from 
[192.168.110.104:10051] is working again
2023/09/18 15:00:47.928815 [101] cannot connect to [192.168.110.104:10051]: dial tcp :0->192.168.110.104:10051: i/o timeout
2023/09/18 15:00:47.928815 [101] active check configuration update from host [GHWS06] started to fail
2023/09/18 15:00:53.926912 [101] active check configuration update from 
[192.168.110.104:10051] is working again
2023/09/18 15:
```

01:08.922329 [101] sending of heartbeat message to [192.168.110.104:10051] is working again

I have taken down windows firewall on the client for the time being. What else to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
cannot connect to [192.168.110.104:10051]
```

Triple check your connection to 192.168.110.104:10051. The I/O timout occurs, when the connection can not be made - due to firewall, av, OS config, router or any other reason.

Comment: I eventually worked out that the shell login to the VMWare flavour of Zabbix was root/zabbix (not Admin). Then I could use telnet for debugging and was able to figure out there was a NAT rule on the interlan traffic.